Trying to deploy a TypeScript project - it works locally but on deployment it doesnt seem to recognize my installed modules
I get this error:
src/store/slices/authSlice.ts(1,44): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@reduxjs/toolkit' or its corresponding type declarations.

I try to deploy my project on render.com
my files structure in the github link here: https://github.com/MeirDavv/shift-management-system.
That's my build command:
cd server && npm i && npm run build && cd ../client && npm i && npm run build

That's my start command:
cd server && npm start

Why it doesn't seem to recognize my installed redux?
I didn't get this issue locally, only on deployment.

Your GitHub repo is missing both the package.json and the package-lock.json. Without these NPM won't install any modules.
